# recur in the rightful tail poistion

Tags: clojure, tail-recursion

[recur](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#recur) should be called in the tail position and I assume that it effectively acts as non-recursive quasi-loop.

Is *expr-1 or 2* regarded in the rightful tail position but none of *expr-3 till 8* in the following mimic block structures? Otherwise, how to reason and identify it before resort to trail and error?

```
(defn foo [x]
 (if cond-expr-1
  (recur expr-1)
  (recur expr-2)))

(defn bar [x]
 (if cond-expr-2
  (fn-1 (recur expr-3))
  (fn-2 (recur expr-4))))

(defn baz [x]
 (if cond-expr-3
  (if cond-expr-4  
    (recur expr-5)
    (recur expr-6))
  (if cond-expr-5  
    (recur expr-7)
    (recur expr-8))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `expr-3` and `expr-4`, it is the argument of a function, and that is why it is not in tail position.

Calling `recur` is basically like a `goto` or `return` statement, both of which cannot be used inside a function argument list.

Since the `if` expression is not a function (it is a "special form"), there is no problem as with a function arg list.

---

Here is a comparison between `loop/recur` and a more imperative approach using `while`:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn fib-recur
  [arg]
  (assert (and (int? arg) (pos? arg)))
  ; initialize state vars
  (loop [N      arg
         result 1]
    (if (zero? N)
      result
      ; compute next state vars
      (let [N-next      (dec N)
            result-next (* result N)]
        (recur N-next result-next))))) ; jump to top of loop with next state vars

(defn fib-while
  [arg]
  (assert (and (int? arg) (pos? arg)))
  ; initialize state vars
  (let [state (atom {:N      arg
                     :result 1})]
    (while (pos? (:N @state)) ; must use newest state value for N in test
      ; compute next state vars
      (let [N          (:N @state)
            result     (:result @state)
            state-next {:N      (dec N)
                        :result (* result N)}]
        (reset! state state-next))) ; save new state & jump to top of loop
    (:result @state)))

(dotest
  (is= 120 (fib-recur 5))
  (is= 120 (fib-while 5)))
```

Comment: So *expr-5 till 8* belong to the right tail calls too, don't they? They're simliar to *expr-1 and 2* in the outmost call stack after being dispatched by the *if* logic branches.

Comment: Yes, `expr-5`, `expr-6` , `expr-7` , and `expr-8`  are all in the tail position.

Answer (score 2):

An expression is in tail position if there is nothing else to be evaluated in the current function following that expression. In your case, all the `recur` invocations in `foo` and `baz` are in tail position and thus both functions will compile fine.

In `bar`, however, neither of the `recur` invocations will be allowed because neither of `expr-3` or `expr-4` are in tail position. There are function calls which uses the result of each `recur` invocation as an argument - that is, the function call logically follows the `recur` invocation, and thus `recur` is not in tail position.

This is not to say that you can't write `bar` to make a recursive invocation of itself, but you have to code it explicitly, as in:

```
(defn bar [x]
 (if cond-expr-2
  (fn-1 (bar expr-3))
  (fn-2 (bar expr-4))))
```

This is absolutely allowed, BUT these recursive invocations of `bar` will consume stack space which means that if the function calls itself recursively enough times you'll run out of stack space. `recur` (and tail recursion in general) is valuable because it doesn't involve making a function call in the traditional sense - instead, (speaking logically here) the function argument on the stack is replaced with the new argument and the code jumps back to the beginning of the function, so no stack space is used. Of course, this means that the original argument in the first call to the function is lost.

Other versions of Lisp do not use the `recur` keyword. When these versions of Lisp find that a function is calling itself recursively they make the same "tail position" determination which Clojure makes and if they find that the call is in tail position they perform the same "replace-the-argument-and-jump" logic Clojure does, while if they find that the call is not in tail position they emit code to perform a "real" recursive call, rather than failing the compilation. Clojure's advantage is that it makes it very obvious to the developer if a call will be compiled as a tail-recursive call (branch) or not.

Comment: Great answer. I wish I could vote to accept  both *@Alan Thompson*'s and yours.